# Why was 61,408 reputation required to run in the 2011 election?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, moderator-election

I was just going through old election pages, and noticed something weird in the sidebar of the [2011 moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1):

> [image: In the nomination page, any community member in good standing with more than 61,408 reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.]

This number only seems to show up in the 2011 election; in later elections, the correct, expected value of 3,000 shows up.

Why was 61,408 reputation required to run in the first election that used the `/election` platform, and why were there a bunch of candidates below the threshold who were allowed to run (there are a few candidates who don't have 61,408 rep)?

Humor aside, why is the sidebar showing an incorrect value for this election, and can it please be fixed?

A similar issue is also occurring on the Mathematics site: the 2014 election [incorrectly states that 1,233 reputation was required to run in that election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5), even though the correct value should be 1,000.

Comment: Only 30 candidates based on reputation can pass into the primary election phase - so the reputation required is 3k up until 30 candidates, and then it becomes the reputation of the 30th placed candidate by rep... so it's possible for the 30th ranked candidate to have nominated with X rep and then another candidate nominates with X+1 rep, making the new reputation X+1, but not cancelling out the previous nomination as it was always there - it would have only prevented the previous candidate from nominating then...

Comment: ... those two theoretical candidates might keep swapping between 30th and 31st places by gaining/losing rep before the primary kicks in, changing the cut off minimum and also which candidate ends up going through to the primary... of course, it's also possible that two more nominations come in with ~2X rep - upping the cut off window and making the other two nominations now look even more odd...

Comment: That's a rather odd hack to do that 

Comment: So it's a relic from a time when there were more than 6 people running?

Comment: @ivarni Yes, I believe so. The "high water" mark in that election rose very quickly (I very nearly didn't make the primary with my humble 10k rep as people with 100k and 200k started nominating). We had a total of 55 nominations as we went into the primary and I'm pretty sure I was at the tail. Jeff was very swift to deal with nominations that weren't serious because they actively blocked people.